# org.olap4j.metadata.Cube or mondrian.olap.Cube?

Tags: java, olap-cube, mondrian, olap4j

I'm developping an olap web application, for the object Cube I have 2 type of import : org.olap4j.metadata.Cube or mondrian.olap.Cube. What should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use the olap4j interfaces. The mondrian implementations are, albeit visible publicly, subject to change without notice.

If there are methods or fields that you think should have been part of the olap4j specifications but are not accessible, I'd encourage you to report your findings to the olap4j  mailing list and we'll review the proposed changes. We're currently drafting the revision 2.0, so now's the best of time to do so.